# Use index as coordinate in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, shader, plot, vbo, opengl-3

I want to implement a timeseries viewer that allows a user to zoom and smoothly pan.

I've done some immediate mode opengl before, but that's now deprecated in favor of VBOs.  All the examples of VBOs I can find store XYZ coordinates of each and every point.

I suspect that I need to keep all my data in VRAM in order to get a framerate during pan that can be called "smooth", but I have only Y data (the dependent variable).  X is an independent variable which can be calculated from the index, and Z is constant.  If I have to store X and Z then my memory requirements (both buffer size and CPU->GPU block transfer) are tripled.  And I have *tens of millions* of data points through which the user can pan, so the memory usage will be non-trivial.

Is there some technique for either drawing a 1-D vertex array, where the index is used as the other coordinate, or storing a 1-D array (probably in a texture?) and using a shader program to generate the XYZ?  I'm under the impression that I need a simple shader anyway under the new fixed-feature-less pipeline model to implement scaling and translation, so if I could combine the generation of X and Z coordinates and scaling/translation of Y that would be ideal.

Is this even possible?  Do you know of any sample code that does this?  Or can you at least give me some pseudocode saying what GL functions to call in what order?

Thanks!

EDIT: To make sure this is clear, here's the equivalent immediate-mode code, and vertex array code:

```
// immediate
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    glVertex2(i, y[i]);
glEnd();

// vertex array
struct { float x, y; } v[N];
for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
    v[i].x = i;
    v[i].y = y[i];
}
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, v);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, N);
```

note that `v[]` is twice the size of `y[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly fine for OpenGL.

Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) can store any information you want in one of GL supported format. You can fill a VBO with just a single coordinate:

```
glGenBuffers( 1, &buf_id);
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf_id );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, N*sizeof(float), data_ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

And then bind the proper vertex attribute format for a draw:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf_id );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // hard-coded here for the sake of example
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
```

In order to use it you'll need a simple shader program. The vertex shader can look like:

```
#version 130
in float at_coord_Y;

void main() {
    float coord_X = float(gl_VertexID);
    gl_Position = vec4(coord_X,at_coord_Y,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Before linking the shader program, you should bind it's at_coord_Y to the attribute index you'll use (=0 in my code):

```
glBindAttribLocation(program_id,0,"at_coord_Y");
```

Alternatively, you can ask the program after linking for the index to which this attribute was automatically assigned and then use it:

```
const int attrib_pos = glGetAttribLocation(program_id,"at_coord_Y");
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm unclear how OpenGL knows I want `coord_X` to mean the index of the vertex.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I missed that initially, sorry :) The answer is fixed now (using gl_VertexID).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now.  And I could use `glDrawArrays` to render this en-masse?  I'm asking because [the manpage for `glDrawArrays`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) says "If GL_VERTEX_ARRAY is not enabled, no geometric primitives are generated."  Does that not apply in the OpenGL 3 world where vertex locations are generated by the shader?

Comment: @Ben Voigt. Yes you can. In GL-3 world you draw everything via glDraw* calls. You do generate vertex positions (and other varyings) in shaders, but there has to be vertex attributes as a source of data (at least one has to be enabled), supplying positions, normals, colors, tex-coords and others.

Comment: It almost worked.  But I still have to turn on GL_VERTEX_ARRAY in order to get any output.  I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Would you store ten millions of XY coordinates, in VRAM?

I would you suggest to compute those coordinates on CPU, and pass them to the shader pipeline as uniforms (since coordinates are fixed to the panned image).

*Keep it simple.*

Comment: When I pan, I need to remove some line segments from the display that moved off-screen, add some that were revealed, and offset the rest by a constant.  Adding a constant to a couple thousand coordinates is quick on the CPU, but then I have to transfer all the data to the GPU again, and I have to do this on every frame while panning is taking place.  Ok, even at 60 FPS this isn't going to be that big a chunk of the PCIe bandwidth, but why waste it?  The GPU can do the math just as easily if I simply send it the new left-most index to be drawn and new translation, and can do it in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand your approach. Panning an image should be implemented by translating the textured quad (bigger than viewport). Texture is (probably) resident, and the only data is an X/Y offset for translating the textured quad. Multiple quads could be used for displaying multiple images.